# Общий хендлер для axios

Tags: javascript, axios

Можно ли для axios сделать общий алгоритм обработки результата? Тоесть сервер может вернуть ошибку, и чтобы при каждом запросе не проверять ее, можно ли это сделать в одном месте?

Comment: Конечно можно. А в чём проблема?

Comment: попробуй почитать про axios interceptors